# How to bind the method of the Control to the method of the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, binding, viewmodel

ObjectProvider has the ability to bind the **method** of the class to the **property** of the Control.

If then is there a functionality to bind the **method** of the Control to the **method** of the ViewModel?

I would like to create a structure which if the method of the ViewModel is called then the method of the Control is called. (because the method of the ViewModel connected with the method of the Control)

Is there any class built-in WPF that supports this functionality?

Comment: you can use attached behavior (which is an attached property). then you will have a property in the viewModel which can "call" a method on the control. sounds awkward? Yeah, it is. And there is a so called ViewService pattern or ViewModel event pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the ICommand Interface.